# Office 2013: Pasting graph from Excel changes decimal separator. Changing the format code turns my axis values into zeroes

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-office-2013

I have created charts in Excel 2013 where I have managed to change the decimal separators to points instead of commas (I'm on a Swedish computer). When pasting these charts to Powerpoint (or Word for that matter), they change back to commas again.

I have been able to solve this before by changing the axis number format or the format code (can't really remember how), but now what seems obvious doesn't work for me. When changing the code from "# ##0,00" to "# ## 0.00" all of my y axis values turns to 0.00, which is even worse than having a comma as decimal separator. I've tried different versions of custom formats, but nothing has worked.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? I have tried changing the system language settings with no luck, and I don't think I should have to do that. This should be easy to fix, right?

Thanks in advance!